# How to initialize Main storyboard from playground

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift-playground

I'm using the following simple code to initialize a storyboard inside playground:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController")

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = controller
```

ViewController is a public class embedded within a cocoa touch framework because I want to share this code with playground but I'm getting this error:

[image]

If I create a new storyboard with a simple UIViewController everything is working.Any ideas?

Comment: try the instantiateInitialViewController method

Comment: I tried but same thing

Comment: How do you embedded and import your framework in Playground?

Comment: I created a new target with cocoa touch framework which contains Main storyboard and all class files.The problem is with Main storyboard and initial view controller if I create a new storyboard its working.

Comment: I see the same error after adding a Storyboard to my Playground (in Resources). The Storyboard has a single UIViewController with a name and ID which I have tried to instantiate just like you did.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution you have to set target membership for Main.storyboard for both framework and your project

Comment: Huh?  From a Playground I don't see how to set target membership for the Main Storyboard, which I have added to Resources. Are you saying that in order to load a Storyboard into a Playground, first we need to create a framework inside a project workspace, then set the target membership?